# Properly designed class with the timers

Tags: c#, optimization, architecture

I have a class that represents some object. This class contains a Timer which triggers some method from time to time.
However, if I write something like this:

```
var obj = new MyClass();
```

Then at the end the object will be deleted and the Timer will not work even a single time.
But I need this object in the memory and I need its work according to the Timer.
So I added an empty Method containing some useless code:

```
while(true){
int k=0;
}
```

Now the Timer works but I don't really like the design.
Any suggestions on how to improve it?

P.S.
This is how I test it: I created a unit test, where I wrote the following:

```
var obj = new MyClass();
int k=0;
```

I have a break point at the second line. And when I reach it, I wait to make sure that Timer never runs. To make the Timer to work, I have to modify the test:

```
var obj = new MyClass();
obj.EmptyWork();
int k=0;
```

Now the timer works but I never reach int k=0; and consequently I can't create the second object ,etc.

Comment: the object you create lives as long as you have a lifespan for it, so if you call a function and it creates the object, but its only defined in that object, then thats how long it lives.. till the end of the function.  you havent shown enough to explain your life span of the object or what you are really doing

Comment: If your timer's event handler is attached to a method in your class, it will keep it alive because timers are rooted until disposed. Post the code where you instantiate and attach the timer, and how you use your class.

Comment: Added more description

Comment: You should use separate threads.

Answer (score 0):

The object is deleted and it is unable to do work because 'at the end' the object will become inaccessible. If you need the object to stick around, you need to make sure it never becomes inaccessible. If the object is created in a function, it needs to be assigned to an external variable or returned from the function.

Comment: When I am in the test method: bar obj = new MyClass(); var k=0; and having a breakpoint at the second line, the object is still accessible and still alive. But the Timer never triggered.

Comment: If the timer is in the same thread and you stop the execution by the breakpoint this is a correct behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to create some scheduler, maybe the better choice is just to create tasks with **Quartz** library: http://www.quartz-scheduler.net

You can isolate the method/class (business logic) from the scheduler (timer), which can be configurable in an easy way.

Sample execution of the "HelloJob" from documentation:

```
// define the job and tie it to our HelloJob class
IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<HelloJob>()
    .WithIdentity("job1", "group1")
    .Build();

// Trigger the job to run now, and then repeat every 10 seconds
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
    .StartNow()
    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
        .WithIntervalInSeconds(10)
        .RepeatForever())
    .Build();

// Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

---

Edited:
You can create work objects, where selected classes implement the IJob (e.g. for Quartz library).
Sample (not tested):

```
interface IWork
{
    void Run(object input);
}

class ImmediateWork : IWork
{
    public void Run(object input)
    {
        // Code to run immediately (without schedule).
    }
}

class ScheduledWork : IWork, IJob
{
    public void Run(object input)
    {
        // Create the schedule for the 'Execute' method.
        var job = JobBuilder.Create<ScheduledWork>().Build();
        var schedule = SimpleScheduleBuilder.RepeatHourlyForTotalCount(10);
        var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create().WithSchedule(schedule).StartNow().Build();
        ScheduleManager.Instance.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        // Code to run after some time (with schedule).
    }
}

// Simple singleton implementation of the global scheduler, for demonstration purposes only.
static class ScheduleManager
{
    private static IScheduler _instance;
    public static IScheduler Instance => _instance ?? (_instance = createInstance());

    private static IScheduler createInstance()
    {
        // Create the instance of the scheduler.
        var schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        var scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();

        // Start the scheduler.
        if (!scheduler.IsStarted)
            scheduler.Start();

        return scheduler;
    }
}
```

---

In case of **MVC** apps; if you really need the timer in your class, which should have a long lifecycle you can try to use **Application State**: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94xkskdf(v=vs.100).aspx